# How to get the input string of Entity as output?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, geography, entity

I have the following codes:-

```
First@GeoNearest["AdministrativeDivision", GeoPosition[{38.6, -90.2}]]
First@GeoNearest["AdministrativeDivision", GeoPosition[{32.3, -106.8}]]
```

Output:-

```
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"StLouisIndependentCity", "Missouri", "UnitedStates"}]
Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"DonaAnaCounty", "NewMexico", "UnitedStates"}]
```

In fact, my desired output are the input-string `StLouisIndependentCity` and `DonaAnaCounty`. I tried to use `Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"StLouisIndependentCity", "Missouri", "UnitedStates"}]["Name"]` (similar to Dona), but the output are the name-string `St. Louis (independent city)` and `Doña Ana County`, which are not what I want.

How can I get it done? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any method that you would normally use to extract data from an expression. Consider that you had this expression:

```
{"AdministrativeDivision", {"StLouisIndependentCity", "Missouri", "UnitedStates"}}
```

How would you extract `"StLouisIndependentCity"` from this? Then do the same for your entity. Here are two suggestions:

```
entity = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"StLouisIndependentCity", "Missouri", "UnitedStates"}];
entity[[2,1]]
```

> `"StLouisIndependentCity"`

Another one:

```
getIdentifier[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {id_, _, _}]] := id
getIdentifier[entity]
```

> `"StLouisIndependentCity"`

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at the [`CanonicalName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CanonicalName.html) accessor.

```
entity = First@GeoNearest["AdministrativeDivision", GeoPosition[{38.6, -90.2}]]
(* Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"StLouisIndependentCity", "Missouri", "UnitedStates"}] *)

CanonicalName[entity]
(* {"StLouisIndependentCity", "Missouri", "UnitedStates"} *)

name[entity_Entity] :=
  Replace[CanonicalName[entity], {en_String, ___} :> en];
name[entity]
(* StLouisIndependentCity *)
```